# How to do batch inner product in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I have two tensor `a:[batch_size, dim]`  `b:[batch_size, dim]`.
I want to do inner product for every pair in the batch, generating `c:[batch_size, 1]`, where `c[i,0]=a[i,:].T*b[i,:]`. How?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no native `.dot_product` method. However, a dot product between two vectors is just element-wise multiply summed, so the following example works:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Arbitrarity, we'll use placeholders and allow batch size to vary,
# but fix vector dimensions.
# You can change this as you see fit
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 3))
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 3))

c = tf.reduce_sum( tf.multiply( a, b ), 1, keep_dims=True )

with tf.Session() as session:
    print( c.eval(
        feed_dict={ a: [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], b: [[2,3,4],[5,6,7]] }
    ) )
```

The output is:

```
[[ 20.]
 [ 92.]]
```

Comment: It solved my problem, thx!

Comment: tf.mul is now tf.multiply. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7032

Comment: There's seemingly nothing TF developers love more than changing the API...

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/batch_dot

Comment: @sajedzarrinpour Thanks. I hope that appeared some time between 2016 and now? Will adjust my answer appropriately

Answer (score 6):

Another option worth checking out is `[tf.einsum][1]` - it's essentially a simplified version of [Einstein Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation).

Following along with Neil and dumkar's examples:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 3))
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 3))

c = tf.einsum('ij,ij->i', a, b)

with tf.Session() as session:
    print( c.eval(
        feed_dict={ a: [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], b: [[2,3,4],[5,6,7]] }
    ) )
```

The first argument to `einsum` is an equation representing the axes to be multiplied and summed over. The basic rules for an equation are:

1. Input-tensors are described by a comma-separated string of dimension-labels
2. Repeated labels indicate that the corresponding dimensions will be multiplied
3. The output-tensor is described by another string of dimension-labels representing corresponding inputs (or products)
4. Labels that are missing from the output string are summed over

In our case, `ij,ij->i` means that our inputs will be 2 matrices of equal shape `(i,j)`, and our output will be a vector of shape `(i,)`.

Once you get the hang of it, you'll find that `einsum` generalizes a huge number of other operations:

```
X = [[1, 2]]
Y = [[3, 4], [5, 6]]

einsum('ab->ba', X) == [[1],[2]]   # transpose
einsum('ab->a',  X) ==  [3]        # sum over last dimension
einsum('ab->',   X) ==   3         # sum over both dimensions

einsum('ab,bc->ac',  X, Y) == [[13,16]]          # matrix multiply
einsum('ab,bc->abc', X, Y) == [[[3,4],[10,12]]]  # multiply and broadcast
```

Unfortunately, `einsum` takes a pretty hefty performance hit when compared to a manual multiply+reduce. Where performance is critical, I'd definitely recommend sticking with Neil's solution.

Answer (score 3):

Taking the diagonal of [tf.tensordot](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensordot) also does what you want, if you set axis to e.g.

```
[[1], [1]]
```

I have adapted Neil Slater's example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Arbitrarity, we'll use placeholders and allow batch size to vary,
# but fix vector dimensions.
# You can change this as you see fit
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 3))
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 3))

c = tf.diag_part(tf.tensordot( a, b, axes=[[1],[1]]))

with tf.Session() as session:
    print( c.eval(
        feed_dict={ a: [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], b: [[2,3,4],[5,6,7]] }
    ) )
```

which now also gives:

```
[ 20.  92.]
```

This might be suboptimal for large matrices though (see discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26168363/elegant-expression-for-row-wise-dot-product-of-two-matrices))

Comment: The march of progress :-), I'm not sure which API version this was added in? I suggest expand your answer with a short example (perhaps based on mine, but it should be simpler, since it won't need the `reduce_sum`)

Comment: I added the example! Actually it also gives off-diagonal dot-products if you don't use tf.diag_part, so your answer will probably be faster. Not really sure in which API version tf.tensordot got introduced, but it might be long ago since it is also available in numpy.

Comment: Wouldn’t this take much more memory than the element-wise multiply and sum?